# html select option tag in php (oracle database)

Tags: php, html, oracle

I have a problem making a select tag in php code dynamic. I'm creating a website (homework) using php and connecting to an oracle database which has all the info needed. Each `agency` has a list of `vehicules`.

I created a `select option` tag for `agencies` and for `vehicules`. I want the data for vehicules to change depending on what agency the user chooses. So if the user chooses `agency A`, the vehicules that should be available on the `select option` tag for vehicules should be that of `agency A1` and no other agency. So far I have all the vehicules of all the agencies in the `select` tag.

I tried creating a function that checks the user's input an selects the vehicule from the agency the user chose. Then it initialise a `$query` in function. And then use that query to fill in my `select` tag. Here is the code

```
function chooseVehicule(){
                    if( ($_POST['agence'])=='CARPORT'){
                        $query='SELECT marque, modele, nom_agence, num_immatriculation from vehicules v, agences ag
                                WHERE v.id_agence=ag.id_agence
                                AND ag.nom_agence=="CARPORT"';
                    }
                }
```

then

```
chooseVehicule();
```

But it gives me `Undefined index: agence` error.
Any ideas please? Here is my complete code.

```
<?php

                function chooseVehicule(){
                    if( ($_POST['agence'])=='CARPORT'){
                        $query='SELECT v.marque, modele, ag.nom_agence, v.num_immatriculation from vehicules v, agences ag
                                WHERE v.id_agence=ag.id_agence
                                AND ag.nom_agence=="CARPORT"';
                    }
                }
        echo '<h3>'; echo 'Pour la location d\'une vehicule, veuillez remplir ce formulaire';echo'</h3>';


               /*CLIENTS*/
               $query="SELECT nom_client from CLIENTS";
               $state=oci_parse($conn, $query);
               oci_execute($state, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

               echo '
                   <form action="location.php" method="post">
                   <p><label for="client">Select your Name</label>
                   <select name="client" id="client">';

               while(($row = oci_fetch_array($state, OCI_BOTH))){
                   echo'<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0]; echo'</option>';
               }
               echo'</select></p>'; 
               echo '</form>';


               /*AGENCES*/
        $query="SELECT nom_agence from AGENCES";
        $state=oci_parse($conn, $query);
                oci_execute($state, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
                echo '
                    <form action="location.php" method="post">
                        <p><label for="agence">Select a Company</label>
                        <select name="agence" id="agence">';

                        while(($row = oci_fetch_array($state, OCI_BOTH))){
                            echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0]; echo'</option>';
                        }

                    echo '</select></p>';
                    echo '</form>';


                /*VEHICULES*/

               $query="SELECT marque, modele, nom_agence, num_immatriculation from vehicules v, agences ag
                       WHERE v.id_agence=ag.id_agence
                       AND type_vehicule='UTILITAIRE'
                       order by nom_agence";

               $state=oci_parse($conn, $query);
               oci_execute($state, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

               echo '
                   <form action="location.php" method="post">
                   <p><label for="vehicule">Select a Vehicule</label>
                   <select name="vehicule" id="vehicule">';
               echo '<optgroup label="Utilitaire">';
               while(($row = oci_fetch_array($state, OCI_BOTH))){
                   echo '<option value="'.$row[3].'">'.$row[2]. ' ' . $row[0] . ' ' . $row[1]; echo '</option>';
               }
               echo '</optgroup>';

               $query="SELECT v.marque, v.modele, ag.nom_agence, v.num_immatriculation from vehicules v, agences ag
                       WHERE v.id_agence=ag.id_agence
                       AND type_vehicule='VOITURE'
                       order by nom_agence";

               echo '<optgroup label="Voiture">';
               $state=oci_parse($conn, $query);
               oci_execute($state, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
               while(($row = oci_fetch_array($state, OCI_BOTH))){
                   echo '<option value="'.$row[3].'">'.$row[2]. ' ' . $row[0] . ' ' . $row[1]; echo '</option>';
               }
               echo '</optgroup>';

               echo'</select></p>'; 
               echo '</form>';

    oci_free_statement($state);
    oci_close($conn);
        ?>
```

I didn't use the function `chooseVehicule` since it gives me an error. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in the `$_POST` superglobal will be sent to the server with the same names as the form fields.  If this form is submitting to itself, you will need to send a field with the name `agence` to avoid this error.  PHP is throwing the error because there is no key `agence` in the `$_POST` array.

In order to bypass this check, since this page is processing numerous forms, you can isset each key first before running a check against it:

```
if( isset($_POST['agence']) && $_POST['agence'])=='CARPORT'){
                        $query='SELECT marque, modele, nom_agence, num_immatriculation from vehicules v, agences ag
                                WHERE v.id_agence=ag.id_agence
                                AND ag.nom_agence=="CARPORT"';
                    }
```

You should do this for all the forms that are sent selectively.

EDIT:

You're going to need to put some state into the page, 'state' in the sense of how far the user has gotten into the selection process.  Let's make it so that the form for vehicles only shows if the user has already selected an agency.  This form should be wrapped in a conditional.

wrap all the logic for the vehicles form in this conditional:

```
if(isset($_POST['agence'])){
  $query="SELECT nom_agence from AGENCES";
    $state=oci_parse($conn, $query);
            oci_execute($state, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
            echo '
                <form action="location.php" method="post">
                    <p><label for="agence">Select a Company</label>
                    <select name="agence" id="agence">';

                    while(($row = oci_fetch_array($state, OCI_BOTH))){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0]; echo'</option>';
                    }

                echo '</select></p>';
                echo '</form>';
}
```

Since this page is procedural, this will make it so that after a selection is made for the agency, then and only then will the vehicle form appear.

We're going to need to make the query for vehicles have a WHERE clause that reflects the selection that was made by the user.  It looks as though you are joining for the id across two tables so the where clause will either need to lookup by agency id or agency name, depending on the database design.

If the vehicle form is put in the conditional like this, we can be certain the user has already made a selection of agency and progressed to the second "state" of the form.  You'll need to then parameterize your sql statement and pass in the selected id.

Comment: Yes the page is posting to itself(it is the same page). I don't understand what you mean by `change the select name attr from client to agence`

Comment: @mkab - Edited, I didn't notice you had several different form elements.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about using `isset`. Let me try it and I would get back to you. Edit:I think there is a problem with the brackets after `$_POST['agence']`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't have the error anymore but the `select` tag isn't working the way I want.

Comment: Can you detail a little better what you want the select tag to do?  Just guess I assume you want it to select a default based off the first submission.  In that case you'd have to compare your query values to the ones in the loop and echo 'selected' for the proper one.

Comment: Ok let me explain it. I have several form elements. I have a form for `agency` which has the `id="agence"` in its select tag.  I also have a form for `vehicules` which also has its select tag. What I want is that: the vehicules that should show in the select tag for `vehicule` should depend on the agency chosen. So if I chose `CARPORT` for example then only the vehicules in the agency `CARPORT` should be shown in the vehicule `select` tag`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your code but it doesn't work. The problem is that the isset would always return false. As a result the agency select tag won't even show up in the browser.

Comment: And if I understand your logic, if the user decides to changes the the agency he/she chose after already chosen one the first time, the list of vehicles won't change. It'd still be the vehicles of the first agency chosen. I have a feeling that i might need to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this isn't set $_POST['agence'].
If you do a isset($_POST['agence']) it will return false.

Comment: Yeah it returns false and `$query` wasn't initialised. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: $_POST['agence'] need be set some place on your code; first of all, check with isset and avoid if returns false; and discover where is the value you need to attribute into $_POST['agence']. Maybe it's a form field mistyped name...